# Transparent walls like the snake game does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make some kind of space shooter game. Now I'm trying to make sure that if my spaceship goes out of view, it comes out on the other side. When I test this it succeeds a few times, but 1: the first time the top of left is incorrect and after that it only works a few times. 2: When I play for some time, my movements slow down exactly like I'm lagging a lot. Can someone help me with this.

PS (don't mind my code, I always make sure it works first and then I take care of my code.)

PS²(You have to run the script in small screen and then turn the ship down to make it work in stackoverflow)

```js
var topP;
    var leftP;
//  let mouseX = 0;
//  let mouseY = 0;
//  let ballX = 0;
//  let ballY = 0;
//  let speed = 0.02;
//  var angle;
    var result
    var Height = window.innerHeight;
    var Width = window.innerWidth;
    var inter;
    var saved_moves = "";
    var count = 6;
    let offset = 0;
    var position = 0;
    var trans = "";
    var newTop = null;
    var newLeft = null;
    let keys = {};
    var turbo = true;
    var speed = 5.0;
    var first = false;
         
          window.onkeyup = function( e ) {
               var kc = e.keyCode;
               

               if ( kc === 37 ) Keys.left = false;
               else if ( kc === 38 ) Keys.up = false;
               else if ( kc === 39 ) Keys.right = false;
               else if ( kc === 40 ) Keys.down = false;
               else if(kc === 13) Keys.enter = false;
             };
             
    window.onload = function() {
        
        plane1 = document.createElement("img")
        plane1.src = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3b/03/94/3b0394153492f7a2e31e80bb9e4c4fb5.gif";
        plane1.style.width = 100 + "px";
        plane1.style.height = 100 + "px"
        plane1.style.position = "relative";
        plane1.setAttribute("id", "plane1")
        plane1.style.top = 400 + "px";
        plane1.style.overflow= "hidden";
        //          parseInt(document.documentElement.scrollHeight / 2)+ "px";
        plane1.style.left = 400 + "px"
        plane1.style.transformOrigin = "center";
        //          parseInt(screen.width / 2) + "px";
        document.getElementById("container").append(plane1)
        topP = plane1.style.top.slice("p")[0]
        leftP = plane1.style.left.slice("p")[0];
        
    
        var base = document.getElementById('plane1')
        var rect = base.getBoundingClientRect();
//      animate()
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function( e ) {
                  if(e.keyCode === 32){
                Fire()
                  }
                  if(e.keyCode === 13){
                      var boost = document.getElementById("boost")
                      if(turbo){
                      speed = 10.0
                      const audio = new Audio("https://sndup.net/xf25/d");
                        audio.volume = 0.9;
                        audio.play();
                      turbo = false;
                      boost.innerHTML ="Boost: "+count;
                      var countdown = setInterval(function() {
                          count--
                          boost.innerHTML ="Boost: "+count;
                        
                      },1000)
                      
                      setTimeout(function() {
                          clearInterval(countdown)
                          count = 6;
                          boost.innerHTML ="Boost: Getting Ready"
                          speed = 5.0;
                          audio.pause()
                          setTimeout(function() {
                              turbo = true;  
                              boost.innerHTML ="Boost: Ready"
                              
                          }, 10000)
                      }, 6000)
                  }
                      else{
                          const audio = new Audio("https://sndup.net/nngh/d");
                            audio.volume = 0.9;
                            audio.play();
                          
                          
                      }
                  }
                 })
        requestAnimationFrame( update );
        setInterval(updateWalls, 500)
        
    }
        function updateWalls(){
            var el = document.getElementById("plane1")

            var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
            if(rect.top <= 0){
                el.style.top = window.innerHeight +"px";
                
            }
            else if(rect.left <= 0){
                el.style.left = window.innerWidth +"px" 
            
            }
            else if(rect.bottom >= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)){
                el.style.top = 0 +"px"
                
            }
            else if(rect.right >= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)){
            el.style.left = 0 +"px"
            
            }
        
            }

            
        
 

    function update() {
        var plane = document.getElementById("plane1")
        saved_moves = document.getElementById("plane1").style.transform;
      if ( Keys.up ) {
        
        plane.style.transform += 'translateY( -'+Math.round(speed )+'px )';
      }
      else if ( Keys.down ) {
       if (speed>1)
       {   
           plane.style.transform += 'translateY( -'+Math.round(speed )+'px )';
       }
    else {
        speed = 1;
        plane.style.transform += 'translateY( 1px )';
    }
      }

      if ( Keys.left ) {
          plane.style.transform += 'rotate( -3deg )';
      }
      else if ( Keys.right ) { 
          plane.style.transform += 'rotate( 3deg )';
      }
      
        requestAnimationFrame( update );
    }
    



    function Fire() {
        var trany = 0;
        var saved = saved_moves
        var i = 5;
        const audio = new Audio("https://sndup.net/xtw5/d");
        audio.volume = 0.9;
        audio.play();
        var bullet = document.createElement("img")
        bullet.src = "https://i.ibb.co/8zTJrZC/bullet.png"
        bullet.style.position = "absolute";
        bullet.style.width = 20 + "px";
        bullet.style.height = 20 + "px";
        bullet.setAttribute("class", "bullet")
        bullet.style.top = document.getElementById("plane1").style.top
        bullet.style.left = document.getElementById("plane1").style.left
        bullet.style.transform = saved_moves;
        document.getElementById("container").append(bullet)
        var inter = setInterval(function(){
            trany -= 7;
            bullet.style.transform = saved + 'translateY('+trany+'vmin)';
            var bullets = document.getElementsByClassName("bullet")
            for(var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++){
                const bounding = bullets[i].getBoundingClientRect();

                if (bounding.top < 0 || bounding.left < 0 || bounding.bottom > (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) || bounding.right > (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) ) {
                    clearInterval(inter)
                    document.getElementById("container").removeChild(bullets[i])
                    trany = 0;
                }
            }
        }, 40)

    }
```

```css
html, body {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
    padding: 0; /* remove default padding */
    width: 100%; /* take full browser width */
    height: 100%; /* take full browser height*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#plane1 {
    transform-origin: center top;
    touch-action: none;
}

body {
    background-image:
        url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/StarfieldSimulation.gif');
    background-size: cover;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

#plane1 {
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#board {
display:table;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top: 0;
width:300px;
height:50px;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="board">
    <h2 id="score">Score: 0</h2>
    <h2 id="boost">Boost: Ready</h2>
    </div>
    <script>
    var Keys = {
            up: false,
            down: false,
            left: false,
            right: false,
            enter: false
          }
    
          window.onkeydown = function( e ) {
            var kc = e.keyCode;
            
            if ( kc === 37 ) Keys.left = true;
            else if ( kc === 38 ) Keys.up = true;
            else if ( kc === 39 ) Keys.right = true;
            else if ( kc === 40 ) Keys.down = true;
            else if(kc === 13) Keys.enter = true;
          };
          
          
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```